# Integer которые передается в static метод, передается как ссылочный Object?

Tags: java

Я думал я Java знаю хорошо. Имеем int - примитивный тип. Когда передаем его в метод, то в методе не ссылка на переменную, а лишь копия. 
Я полагал что Integer, полноценный класс упаковки int передается в метод по ссылке и любые манипуляции с переменной Integer переданные в метод будут происходить непосредственно с той переменной которую мы передали, а не какой то копией.

Я не понимаю, почему следующий код работает против моего понимания типов в Java.

```
Integer a=5;
inc(a);
System.out.println(a);

 private static void inc(Integer a){
        a++;
    }
```

Output:

```
5
```

Объясните, почему 5, а не 6???

Comment: при чем здесь тот факт, что метод статический?

Comment: Как я понял, то как я хочу что бы работал код реализуемо только int[1]={5}

Comment: А разве здесь не банальное перекрытие поля `a`? В методе приняли, увеличили на 1, но `a = 6` это уже локальная переменная в самом методе.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы все правильно сказали, все аргументы при вызове метода в java передаются по значению, но тут один нюанс. `java.lang.Integer` является неизменяемым  типом, и когда происходит инкрементирование, то выполняется `unboxing`, увеличение значения и снова упаковка в объект, т.е. создается уже совсем другой объект.

Comment: А как тогда передать Integer в метод, что бы иметь возможность изменить значение которое закреплено по ссылке переменной?

Comment: Тут несколько вариантов,1) передавайте массив или какой то wrapper, 2) возвращайте измененное значение из метода или же 3) откажитесь от Integer и замените его на какой нибудь mutable аналог, например AtomicInteger (не советую)

Comment: «параметры в java за исключением примитивных типов передаются по ссылке» – я, конечно, понял, что Вы имели ввиду, но лучше так не писать, дабы не вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: )) @post_zeew извините, я правда не знаю, а как правильно?

Comment: «все аргументы в Java передаются при вызове по значению» (с).

Comment: @post_zeew Спасибо, поправлю в соответствии с терминологией.

Comment: Возможно Вы меня не так поняли, в той фразе ключевое слово – по значению. Не по ссылке, а по значению. Все по значению. Только вот тут стоит сразу оговориться... у Шилдта по этому поводу хорошо написано в «Подробное рассмотрение особенностей
передачи аргументов».

Comment: @post_zeew что вы имеете ввиду под значением? если указатель на объект то ок, если же сам объект, то это не верно. Потому что, при вызове метода не происходит копирования аргумента и его дальнейшей передачи, передается только ссылка. А с примитивами, как раз происходит то что вы говорите, т.к. ссылки на них нельзя создать из за этого они честно копируются и передаются в метод.

Comment: @post_zeew да вы правы, в java все по значению передается.

Comment: А можно список неизменяемых объектов, я думал, что, только String неизменяемый

Comment: В случае объектов я имею ввиду ссылку на объект. Указатель? В Java же нет указателей (ну, по крайней мере тех, которые, например, есть в C++).

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa Навскидку все классы-обертки для примитивов, BigInteger, BigDecimal, классы из пакета java.time.*

Answer (score 6):

Согласно [JLS 15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

> The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a numeric type...
>   ...  the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable.
>   Note that the binary numeric promotion mentioned above may include unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)

Далее, JLS 5.1.8 гласит:

> 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion
>   If r is a reference of type Integer, then unboxing conversion converts r into r.intValue()

Таким образом, вычисляется `a.intValue()`, которое увеличивается на 1.

Возвращается к 15.14.2:

> If necessary, the sum is ... subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored.

Таким образом, результат боксируется в `Integer`, и присваивается локальной переменной `a`.

Answer (score 2):

В этом предложении

```
a++;
```

объект `a` распаковывается, создавая временный объект примитивного типа, который увеличивает свое значение. Сам объект `a` типа `Integer` остается неизменным.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` является `immutable` объектом и при инкриментации создается новый объект.